# CSS3 Transitions in Media Queries?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have been working on a responsive design website that utilizes CSS3 transitions and media queries. As such, I have created several divs with the class name of "slider". I have two rules in my CSS, one to declare the hover states width and another to specify the transition.

For example:

```
#navcontainer .slider:hover{
width: 38px;
}
#navcontainer .slider{
-webkit-transition: width 2s;
}
```

The following will work, but does not when I add another rule inside of a media query like such:

```
@media(max-width: 440px){
#navcontainer .slider:hover{width: 56px;}
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It should be working... But I normally use "@media only screen and (max-width: 440px){}", not only @media(){}.

Your media queries are at the bottom of your css file? (it shouldn't make any difference, but who knows?). Also, I think you should be using other vendor prefixes for your transitions:

```
transition:...;
-o-transition:...;
-moz-transition:...;
-webkit-transition:...;
```

I would also try to copy those lines of transition to inside of the @media(){}

And again, I think it should be working just the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

You know the `@media` selector in your questions is a `:hover`, right?

Seems to work just fine for me. [In this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/k8ePf/) I've added a background change for the `@media` rule so it's more obvious, just slide the middle border left and right to resize the pane and trigger the `@media` styles.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/k8ePf/

Comment: Thanks for you help. It seems as though there was an issue with browser cache in Chrome, and my previous attempts were nullified.